# Оптимизация цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, pandas, excel

Организую перенос из SQL в Excel (сам эксель содержит ID), после чего по ID (в экселе) присваиваю ФИО (сама задача обширнее, для простоты привожу часть). Трудность заключается в том, что на обработку ячейки уходит полминуты, если их несколько тысяч, данные будут обрабатываться очень долго. Думаю над такими вариантами:

1. через цикл организовать запрос в SQL и доставать сразу нужное мне значение (можно ли питоновскую переменную передать в sql? если да, то как?)
2. так как я обрабатываю строковое значение ID (пример: 5855830884210365) решил перевести в np.int64, но на скорости это почти никак не сказалось (этот вариант отпадает? или можно его как-то переписать?)
   Буду рад любым советам. Код:

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
server = 'DMITRY\SQLEXPRESS'
database = 'RGSNEW1'
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#можно ли тут объявить переменную, к примеру, так: a = '5855830884210365'
query = ("""
               SELECT Pers.Surname, Pers.ID 
FROM Pers 
# чтобы потом вставить сюда WHERE Pers.ID = a
""")
dtb = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
dtb.index += 1
xlsx = pd.read_excel("dat1.xlsx", dtype={"A6" : str,"A8" : str})
xlsx.index += 1
dtb2 = dtb.copy(deep=True)
fll = pd.concat([xlsx, dtb2], axis=1)
#меняю тип нужных мне столбцов на np.int64, трайэксепты затем, чтобы пропустить выбросы
for ind in range (0, len(fll)):
    print(ind)
    try:
       fll.at[ind + 1, 'A6'] = np.int64(fll.iloc[ind]['A6'])
    except ValueError:
       continue
for ind in range (0, len(fll)):
    print(ind)
    try:
       fll.at[ind + 1, 'id'] = np.int64(fll.iloc[ind]['id'])
    except ValueError:
       continue
#начинаю перебирать значения и по id (ячейка "A6" содержит id, по которому ищут, столбец id взят с sql) добавляю значение Surname в столбец "A51"
for ind1 in range (0, 25):
   print(ind1)
   for ind in range (0, len(fll)):
      if fll.iloc[ind1]['A6'] == fll.iloc[ind]['id']:
         fll.at[ind1+1, 'A51'] = fll.iloc[ind]['surname']
         break
#fll.to_excel("drr.xlsx")
```

Comment: Который раз уже при публикации удаляется приветствие, на стаке здороваться не принято?)

Comment: посмотрите пример на главной странице проекта pypyodbc на git. https://github.com/pypyodbc/pypyodbc  обратите внимание на строки, где параметры заменены знаками `?` и параметры передаются дополнительным массивом в execute

Comment: Сделал немножко иначе:
'''
id = '5855830884210365'
query = (f"""
   SELECT  Pers.Surname, Pers.ID
   FROM Pers
   WHERE Pers.ID = '{id}'
 """)
'''

Comment: В общем случае такая подстановка не безопасна. Например, если в id вдруг окажется текст с кавычкой запрос сломается. Вопросительный знак и передача параметров отдельно, явно говорит БД что это именно значения, а не часть синтаксиса

Comment: у меня и идет число как текст (в кавычки заключил), с вопросом не разобрался, у меня постоянно ошибки появлялись при попытке вывода (сам запрос вроде как отрабатывал) или вы имеете ввиду внутри будет текст с кавычкой, к примеру так: 'тек'ст'

Comment: Ну это у вас и именно здесь. Я же говорю в общем случае, вдруг что то еще писать будете и начнете с БД так работать, а там в переменной пользовательский ввод окажется. До половины всех взломов сайтов в интернете происходят из за таких подстановок

Comment: Ввода не будет, будет считывание этого id c датафрейма и по нему отрабатываться запрос. Спасибо за замечание!